# Rails delayed_jobs get deleted from database without processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, backgroundworker, background-process

I have implemented delayed_job_active_record as background proccess in my project and run the application on Heroku with 1 worker process.

```
Ruby 2.2.4
Rails 4.0.4
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '4.1.0'
```

/app/models/contact_sync_job.rb

```
class ContactSyncJob < Struct.new(:user)
    def perform

        user.contacts.each do |c|
            #process contacts
        end

    end
end
```

I call the delayed job in controller

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(ContactSyncJob.new(current_user))
```

Issue:
Background process is not working and record is removed from delayed_jobs table without any process.

There is no error reported on Heroku logs, what I can notice is the record get added to delayed_jobs table and get deleted immediately.

Also when I enable debug mode on production I can see that the worker runs the following query.

```
UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = '2016-05-19 10:36:33', `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'host:c7652e73-a59a-4268-ba8b-ec71c224d4b1 pid:3' WHERE ((run_at <= '2016-05-19 10:36:33' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2016-05-19 10:31:33') OR locked_by = 'host:c7652e73-a59a-4268-ba8b-ec71c224d4b1 pid:3') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
```

But the record is immediately deleted and not processed.

I have configured,

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
```

But the job is not marked as error either.

Comment: `job = Delayed::Job.where("last_error is not null").last` and
`puts job.last_error` try running these two commands and see if you get more information about the error

Comment: This returns nil - There is no record on the table that report as error. Delayed job record is inserted to the DB and immediately deleted before a worker lock the record for processing.

Comment: Can you add log from the terminal where it's says delayed job inserted ?

Comment: Please see here[link] https://gist.github.com/anonymous/00323b4cdc5e70526583ee275a106703